# Error related to translation using Azure's Translate API (ErrorCode: 400000)

Tags: azure, powershell, translate, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to translate Office365 incident information using Translate API in Azure.
However, there are some sentences that cannot be translated because the following error is displayed.
I have some sentences that I can translate, but I didn't understand the differences from the ones that produced an error and asked a question.
I think that the number of characters is not the cause because some sentences succeed and some fail with the same number of characters. Is there any other restriction? ..
The text is long and very troubled, but please answer.

[error]

Invoke-RestMethod: {"error": {"code": 400000, "message": "One of the request inputs is not valid."}}

[Example of error text1]

> Title: Unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment within the admin consoleUser Impact: Admins may be unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status on the admin console.Current status: We believe that a recent change to the service may be causing impact. We're investigating what the exact changes were to determine the n
>   ext troubleshooting steps.  Scope of impact: Impact is specific to any administrator attempting to view compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status.  Next update by: Tuesday, May 19, 2020, at 11:00 AM UTC  Title: Unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment within the admin consoleUser Impact: Admins may be unable to see compliance 
>   policy and configuration profile deployment status on the admin console.Current status: We're continuing to review the recent changes made to help isolate the source of the issue.  Scope of impact: Impact is specific to any administrator attempting to view compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status.  Next update by: Tuesday, May 19, 2020, at 1:00 PM UTC
>   Title: Unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment within the admin consoleUser Impact: Admins may be unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status on the admin console.Current status: Investigation into the root cause is still ongoing. However, we're developing a fix and will apply it across the affected infrastructure
>    after we've tested it in our internal environment.  Scope of impact: Impact is specific to any administrator attempting to view compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status.  Next update by: Tuesday, May 19, 2020, at 6:00 PM UTC Title: Unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment within the admin consoleUser Impact: Admins may have 
>   been unable to see compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status on the admin console.Final status: We've identified a recent configuration change caused a routing rule to be incorrectly applied, resulting in impact. We've completed deploying the fix and confirmed impact has been mitigated via telemetry.Scope of impact: Impact was specific to any administrat
>   or attempting to view compliance policy and configuration profile deployment status.Start time: Tuesday, May 19, 2020, at 2:36 AM UTCEnd time: Tuesday, May 19, 2020, at 3:40 PM UTCRoot cause: A recent configuration change caused a routing rule to be incorrectly applied, resulting in impact.Next steps:- We're reviewing our update procedures to better identify similar configu
>   ration issues during our development and testing cycles.This is the final update for the event.

[Example of error text2]

> Title: Email profiles can't be created within Microsoft IntuneUser Impact: Users may be unable to create email profiles or edit provisioned profiles within Microsoft Intune.Current status: We're analyzing diagnostic data to determine next troubleshooting steps.Scope of impact: All users are impacted by this event.Next update by: Thursday, May 21, 2020, at 2:30 PM UTC Title:
>    Email profiles can't be created within Microsoft IntuneUser Impact: Users may be unable to create email profiles or edit provisioned profiles within Microsoft Intune.Current status: A recent update, designed to improve user experience features, has unexpectedly resulted in impact to email profiles where a certificate is required. We're evaluating the changes made in the up
>   date to develop a mitigation plan.Scope of impact: All users are impacted by this event.Root cause: A recent user experience features update, unexpectedly caused impact to email profiles where a certificate is required.Next update by: Thursday, May 21, 2020, at 4:30 PM UTC Title: All users can't create email profiles within Microsoft IntuneUser Impact: Users may be unable t
>   o create email profiles or edit provisioned profiles within Microsoft Intune.Current status: We've identified the impacting code and have developed and validated a fix. We've initiated deployment to the impacted infrastructure. Users will begin to experience relief as the deployment progresses through their environment. We expect the deployment to complete by 10:30 PM UTC, 
>   on Thursday, May 21, 2020.Scope of impact: All users are impacted by this event.Start time: Friday, May 15, 2020, at 8:46 PM UTCEstimated time to resolve: We expect the deployment to complete by 10:30 PM UTC on Thursday, May 21, 2020.Root cause: A recent user experience features update unexpectedly caused impact to email profiles where a certificate is required.Next update 
>   by: Thursday, May 21, 2020, at 11:30 PM UTC Title: All users can't create email profiles within Microsoft IntuneUser Impact: Users may have been unable to create email profiles or edit provisioned profiles within Microsoft Intune.Final status: Our deployment of the fix has completed and we’ve confirmed via telemetry that impact is mitigated.Scope of impact: All users were i
>   mpacted by this event.Start time: Friday, May 15, 2020, at 8:47 PM UTCEnd time: Thursday, May 21, 2020, at 10:05 PM UTCRoot cause: A recent user experience features update unexpectedly caused impact to email profiles where a certificate is required.Next steps:- We're analyzing our update procedures to better catch similar issues during our development and testing cycles.Thi
>   s is the final update for the event.

[Code]

```
$Message = [Text to translate]
$body = @{'Text' = $($Message)} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $constructed_url -Headers $headers -Body "[$($body)]"
```

Comment: It looks like an error due to specific characters, I would say especially single quotes which are not escaped, like in your case "We're". Can you check your exact body payload?

Comment: Append the full text of the error to the original text.
Indeed, both sentences contain "We're" so they can appear in certain letters. I will check it.

Comment: I tried the following as a verification and got the same error.

`$body -replace "'",""`

Answer (score 0):

When I'm trying your Error Text1 in Postman, copy pasting all the field shows me a line return (after "at 1:00 PM UTC") which is breaking my JSON as you can see below:

[image]

Can you check if you have '\r' or '\n' characters in your text field? And escape those fields.

When I check your Error Text2 in Postman, I got a correct reply

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
As I told you, I escaped "\ r" and "\ n" and other sentences were processed correctly.
Thank you for your response. It was helpful.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't hesitate to validate the answer if it solves your problem